# collapsible content won't fit on height of content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script down below, it should expand to the height of the full content after clicking the button "Read more". It workes almost, but there is still a small problem with the height, it doesn't expand to full height of the content and cuts it halfway. I presume that there is a mistake inside the script.

```js
  (function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.readMoreFade = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            backgroundColor: "white",
            buttonClass: "button"
        }, options );

        this.css( "height", 100 );
        this.css( "overflow", "hidden" );
        this.css( "position", "relative" );
        this.append('<p class="readMoreFade"><a href="#" class="' + settings.buttonClass + '">Read More</a></p>')

        var readMoreButton = this.find('.readMoreFade');
        var backgroundString = settings.backgroundColor ? settings.backgroundColor : this.css('background-color');

        readMoreButton.css('background-image', '-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, rgba(255,0,0,0)),color-stop(1, '+backgroundString+'))');
        readMoreButton.click(function(){
                totalHeight = 0

                $el = $(this);
                $p  = $el;
                $up = $p.parent();
                $ps = $up.find("p:not('.readMoreFade')");

                $ps.each(function() {
                    totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
                });

                $up
                    .css({
                        "max-height": 9999
                    })
                    .animate({
                        "height": totalHeight
                    });
                $p.fadeOut();
                return false;
        })

        return this;
    };
}( jQuery ));

$('#fadeMe').readMoreFade({buttonClass: "btn btn-primary"});
```

```css
#fadeMe{
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 420px;
    margin:30px auto;
    font-family:'Roboto';
}
.readMoreFade {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgba(255,0,0,0)), color-stop(1, rgba(255,0,0,100)));
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fadeMe">
    <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac arcu id magna sollicitudin fermentum. Quisque tristique eros ex, vitae bibendum metus scelerisque a. Donec posuere leo vestibulum dui vestibulum, non faucibus metus vestibulum. Suspendisse commodo at orci ac lobortis. Mauris vestibulum, orci eu feugiat imperdiet, erat urna lobortis ante, vitae porttitor erat eros finibus massa. Aenean congue urna posuere nisl lobortis sollicitudin. In sed iaculis velit, eu tempor lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque laoreet finibus dapibus. Duis eget metus sem. Cras non tempor dui, in euismod leo.</p>
    <p>Sed justo felis, venenatis vel est sit amet, varius varius libero. Nam a ligula et tellus posuere malesuada a ultricies felis. Curabitur vitae magna lectus. Nam consequat vitae neque et varius. Nunc mollis lacus non varius rutrum. Nulla et ex vitae lectus rhoncus ultricies. Proin fringilla id risus ut finibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris vitae molestie diam.</p>
    <p>Sed justo felis, venenatis vel est sit amet, varius varius libero. Nam a ligula et tellus posuere malesuada a ultricies felis. Curabitur vitae magna lectus. Nam consequat vitae neque et varius. Nunc mollis lacus non varius rutrum. Nulla et ex vitae lectus rhoncus ultricies. Proin fringilla id risus ut finibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris vitae molestie diam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle and I will help

Comment: Here you go Chris: https://jsfiddle.net/33rs7wag/ Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've read your javascript correctly, you are getting the height of all of the p tags and setting the 'fadeMe' div to that height. Your 'fadeMe' div has a padding of 1em, so make sure you add at least 2em to your 'totalHeight' variable.

Please let me know if this works :)

Add the following lines under you $ps loop -

```
var divPadding = Number($up.css("padding").replace("px", "")) * 2;
totalHeight = totalHeight + divPadding;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it. But Is there a possibility to determine the height without adding all <p> together? Because some content contains also tables or spans and this leads to the same problem.

Comment: Sure, you could place the content of the fadeMe div within another div, give it an Id and then get the height of that div. For example $uc = $up.find("#contentDiv"); 
totalHeight = $uc.outerHeight();
The above can replace the $ps logic.

Comment: Thanks very much Rob!

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to mark the answer as a solution :)